# Characters classes in ranges - vim

Tags: regex, vim, special-characters, character-class

Given I have the following string:

```
This is a test {{ string.string.string }}.
```

And try to perform the following substitution:

```
%s/{{ [\w\.]\+ }}/substitute/g
```

It will not work with the error: Pattern not found.

When I use:

```
%s/{{ [a-zA-Z\.]\+ }}/substitute/g
```

It works.

Is there a way to use the meta-character-classes in ranges in VIM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

- A non capturing sub-expression, see `:help E53` (you can use a capturing sub-expression as well, `\(\)`, but the overhead of capturing is useless)

  ```
  %s/{{ \%(\w\|\.\)\+ }}/substitute/g
  ```
- A sequence of optionally matched atoms - `\%[]`, see `:help E70`

  ```
  %s/{{ \%[\w\.]\+ }}/substitute/g
  ```