# match wordchar and/or dot string of anylength

Tags: regex, vim

This matches a word `/\w\+`
This matches a any number of dots `/\.\+`

Why doesn't this match any number of words combined by dots? `/[\w\.]\+` ?

The w seems to be matching actual 'w's instead of a word character, whether I escape it or not.

Comment: I just realized I can do this instead `/[a-zA-z\.]\+`

Comment: `\w` has a different meaning inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html).

Comment: What engine does vim use?

Comment: @vrmc - don't see `vim` in their list.

Comment: @sln good point. I should've linked to something vim-specific like [this](http://vimregex.com/#metacharacters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "PREDEFINED RANGES" in [Vim documentation: usr_27](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_27.html#27.6):

> Note:
>     Using these predefined ranges works a lot faster than the character range it stands for.
>     These items can not be used inside `[]`. Thus `[\d\l]` does **NOT** work to     match a digit or lowercase alpha. Use `\(\d\|\l\)` instead.

So, your work-around would be `/[a-zA-Z\.]\+` if you want to exclude digits and underscore that are matched with `\w`, or `/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]\+` to emulate the `\w` functionality.
If POSIX bracketed classes are supported, `/[[:alpha:]\.]\+` (or for full emulation, `/[[:alpha:][:digit:]_\.]\+`) is also an option.

There are also other ways, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845631/3832970) where 2 other alternatives are suggested:

- A non-capturing sub-expression`\%(\w\|\.\)\+`
- A sequence of optionally matched atoms `\%[\w\.]\+`